# How do I unit test a class that relies on HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, webforms, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to add tests to a webforms project. There's a static method to grab lines from resource files. One of the classes I'm trying to test, relies on grabbing text from the resource file.

```
public static class MyStaticClass {
    public static string getText(String name)
    {
        String s = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResources", name).ToString();
        return s;
    }
}

public class ClassUnderTest
{
    // returns: "Hey it's my text"
    private string _eg = MyStaticClass.getText("label_in_resources.resx_file")
}

class UnitTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMyClass()
    {
        ClassUnderTest _cut = new ClassUnderTest();
        // errors out because ClassUnderTest utilizes getText
        // which requires HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject
        // ... other stuff
    }
}
```

Note: these are simplistic examples.

The issue is that I get a Test Failed with the message:

> Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

With my sleuthing, I've determined that this is because `HttpContext` is null during these tests.

I've looked at quite a few SO posts on mocking `HttpContext` but I don't think that I fully understand what exactly they're doing as they're typically dealing with MVC and not Webforms. Still most of them use `HttpContextBase` and/or `HttpContextWrapper` but again, I'm not sure how to implement them.

Also - I'm not directly testing the `getText` method. I know it works. I'm testing a class that uses it. Will mocking the `HttpContext` even help in this situation?

I do realize that this is sort of a hybrid of a unit test / integration test, so if this isn't the best way, I'm all ears... or.. eyes rather.

**Edit**

For now, I modified my `getText` method to return the key (name) if the result of `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject` is null. Then I updated my tests to expect the key instead of the value. It's not ideal, but it works and allows me to continue. If there's a better way, please let me know.

```
public static class MyStaticClass {
    public static string getText(String name)
    {
        String s = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResources", name);
        return s != null ? s.ToString() : name;
    }
}
```

Comment: A solution to replace `GetGlobalResourceObject` entirely with a wrapper  that has an interface would be your best bet. However, if you cannot, I found Microsoft Fakes to be my go to for having to mock statics when testing.

Comment: @TyCobb Could you provide an example? I believe I'm already wrapping `GetGlobalResourceObject` unless I'm misunderstanding. Also, in case it wasn't clear, I'm not testing the static method itself directly, but that is where the error is stemming from.

Comment: I'm working on one. I missed that `getText` was static. You can just fake that class. Working on an example now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer with Fakes (see below for dealing with removing static)**

So there's one caveat that I completely forgot about until I just tried to do this. I am pretty sure Fakes still requires Enterprise version of VS. I don't know if there's a way to get it to work with NUnit, but when you aren't able to change the code sometimes you have to just deal with it.

Here's an example of Shimming your static method. You don't need to worry about HttpContext (yet) since you aren't using it directly. Instead you can Shim your `getText(string)` method.

*Actual Business Project*

```
namespace FakesExample
{
    public class MyStaticClass
    {
        public static string GetText(string name)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
    }
}
```

*Your Unit Test Project*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace FakesExampleTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                FakesExample.Fakes.ShimMyStaticClass.GetTextString = (s) =>
                {
                    return "Go away null reference";
                };

                Console.WriteLine(FakesExample.MyStaticClass.GetText("foo"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I actually ran this so I know it works. What happens is that even though `GetText` will always throw a NullReferenceException when called, our Shim of it returns our own custom message.

*You may have to make a Visual Studio Test Project.*

In your Unit Test project, right-click your reference and say "Add Fakes". It will generate all of the Shims and Stubs for your assembly.

---

**Process of removing the static**

The best solution is to actually work towards removing the static. You've already hit one major reason to not use them.

Here's how I would go about removing the static and removing the dependency on HttpContext

```
public interface IResourceRepository
{
    string Get(string name);
}

public class HttpContextResourceRepository : IResourceRepository
{
    public string Get(string name)
    {
        return HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResources", name).ToString();
    }
}

public class MyFormerStaticClass
{
    IResourceRepository _resourceRepository;

    public MyFormerStaticClass(IResourceRepository resourceRepository)
    {
        _resourceRepository = resourceRepository;
    }

    public string GetText(string name)
    {
        return _resourceRepository.Get(name);
    }
}
```

I would then leverage Dependency Injection to handle the creation of my `HttpContextResourceRepository` and `MyStaticClass` (which should probably also be interfaced) in the actual business code.

For the unit test, I would mock the implementation

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var repoMock = new Mock<IResourceRepository>();
        repoMock.Setup(repository => repository.Get("foo")).Returns("My Resource Value");

        var formerStatic = new MyFormerStaticClass(repoMock.Object);
        Console.WriteLine(formerStatic.GetText("foo"));
    }
}
```

Going this route, you can create any number of IResourceRepository implementations and swap them whenever you want.

Comment: I don't have Enterprise unfortunately. Unrelated: I like your avatar. :)

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but then you need to overhaul your stuff and stop using statics. That stuff needs to be abstracted away. Edit: Thanks xD

Comment: I don't think the static is the issue. The issue is that there isn't an `HttpContext` to get the value from the `.resx` files. I think what I'll end up doing is modifying my `getText` method so that if the context doesn't exist, it will just return the string identifier instead. At least then I'll be able to continue along and I can modify my tests to expect the key rather than the value.

I'm not sure I can abstract this away. And if I can, then I'm not entirely sure how to go about it.

Comment: No, the static is exactly the issue -- you can't mock your own class! Your proposal to fix it is now going to change the output of your system. Look into SOLID.

Comment: Well when you put it that way... :/ I know what you're saying, however, the class under test sets private members to the values of the static method. The methods that I'm testing use those private members. I'm a little new to mocking, so I'll look into mocking those private members.

Comment: @gin93r I have updated my answer. I strongly suggest you look into it.

Comment: Ha! I was just coming back to here to say that I've refactored my class to have an interface and I'm mocking the interface. So far so good. I think I'm on the right track now. Thanks :D

Comment: Excellent! You have seen the light! ;)

Comment: For sure. I went about it a little differently, but I think it will be ok. I'm still using the static. I'll look into removing that in the future. But for now, I can at least mock what those values are.